# CORS "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: angularjs, cors

I have an error with CORS:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://graphql-swapi.parseapp.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405."

Error when I call a service method.

**Code Snippet:**

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

//console.log(headers);

return this._http.post(apiUrl, { query: query, vars: '{}' }, { headers: headers })
  .map(res => res.json().data.planets);
```

When I disable CORS in the browser, I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxx. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 error.

A query and code is for sure correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The response had HTTP status code 405

[Look that up](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> 405 Method Not Allowed

---

> Response to preflight request

[Look that up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests):

> "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send

---

Your server side code is, presumably, set up to add the CORS headers to the response to a POST request, but you haven't set it up to handle an OPTIONS request at all.

Comment: How can I solve it? I have to change server code or just something in app code?

Comment: You have to change the server code so it can handle the options request.

Comment: You should also change the client side code so it isn't trying to set the CORS **response** headers as if they were **request** headers. Your code can't give itself permission to access other sites, that would make having the restriction pointless.